# Mesos bind error : Cannot assign requested address [99]

Tags: mesos

I'm trying to run a Mesos cluster on 2 machines. One is a server that I rent (we'll call it **S1**), and the other one is a machine running in my house (**S2**). The Mesos slaves and masters are running inside Docker containers.

First, I ran into this error : https://github.com/mesos/chronos/issues/193.
I followed the advices in this post (by setting either `LIBPROCESS_IP` or `MESOS_IP`). Adding one of these environment variables causes this error :

```
F0512 08:48:55.437530     1 process.cpp:889] Failed to initialize: Failed to bind on <ip>:<port>: Cannot assign requested address: Cannot assign requested address [99]
```

I figured it was caused because the Docker container ip address was 172.17.0.1 and not S1 or S2's ip. I added `--net=host` in the docker run command. It fixed the error on S1, but not on S2.

I think it is because S2 has a local IP inside my network (192.168.0.16), and mesos can't bind to my router IP.

Is there a way to make Mesos work with this configuration, or do I need a machine with its own IP address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this doesn't seem to be an ideal configuration, you might have success in adding a port forwarding on your router (e.g. port 5050 and 5051) and use the `--advertise_ip` command line flag when starting the master/slave on the machine in your house.

> IP address advertised to reach this Mesos master/slave. The master/slave does not bind to this IP address. However, this IP address may be used to access this master/slave.

See

- http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/

Comment: I had tried this parameter but for some reason I had errors with it. Just tried and I can start a master, which communicates correctly with Zookeeper. However, it doesn't detect any slaves. The slave sees the Master, though. In the slaves' logs we can see `New master detected at master@<ip>:<port>`, with the correct IP and port...

Comment: The masters don't "detect" the slaves, the slaves register with the master node in ZooKeeper, so I guess there was another problem. You should post the logs, otherwise it'll be difficult to help

Comment: btw, have you used the router's IP address for `--advertise_ip`? And, for sure, you'd need to set the port forwarding as well

Comment: What's weird is that the slave is able to register with the master, but on Mesos web interface, it looks like there is 0 slave. That's what I meant by 'detect any slaves', sorry !
You're right, this is probably another problem. I'll create another question since this one is technically answered.
For the information, I do have used my router's IP address, and forwarded the ports 5051, 5052, (because the port 5050 was already taken by something else, master is running on 5051 and slave on 5052) 8081 and 7077, to try to launch Spark's `MesosClusterDispatcher`.

Comment: Well I've noticed a line in the logs : `E0513 08:25:11.201673    14 process.cpp:1958] Failed to shutdown socket with fd 11: Transport endpoint is not connected`, it looks like the Slave knows who the master is but can't connect to it. Is the slave communicating with the master on the defined port (5050 or 5051 for me) ? I can remember reading somewhere in the logs some weird ports number (e.g. 17845), a few days ago.

Comment: Is the hostname resolvable, meaning does it map to the actual IP address(es) that the processes bound to? E.g. is there an entry in the `/etc/hosts` other than `127.0.0.1   localhost`? Furthermore, I really think you should use the standard ports for port forwarding in your router, i.e. 5050 for the master and 5051 for the slave... Or, you also need to use `--advertise_port=5051` on the host running in your home